# Where can I find getLevel()?

Tags: python, pyaudio

In the code below is using `getLevel()`. where can I find it (it is about sound, and it run with pyaudio library)

```
# this is the threshold that determines whether or not sound is detected
THRESHOLD = 0

#open your audio stream    

# wait until the sound data breaks some level threshold
while True:
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    # check level against threshold, you'll have to write getLevel()
    if getLevel(data) > THRESHOLD:
        break

# record for however long you want
# close the stream
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at https://docs.python.org/library/audioop.html
This is another python module to handle audio, but that one does seem to have a method to get the audio level ( max(fragment, width) ).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the imports that have been executed. You'll either find `from someModule import getLevel`, or `from someModule import *`.

Comment: But in the module pyaudio I can't find this function. I don't know in which module I can find it

Comment: No one told you to look in pyaudio. Look in the code you have in front of you.